# Complete Stotra of Shiva

Tags: shiva, mantras, stotra

It looks like the below stotra or mantra is not complete. This stotra of Shiva is taken from Yajurveda. Can anyone provide details about where in Yajurveda, this stotra is mentioned and also the complete chapter text related to this stotra.

कर्पूरगौरं करुणावतारं
संसारसारम् भुजगेन्द्रहारम् ।
सदावसन्तं हृदयारविन्दे
भवं भवानीसहितं नमामि ॥

Comment: Everywhere only this much is found. For example see Greenmesg.com : http://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/karpura_gauram.php

Comment: @Rickross yes. But people have a tendency to shorten big stotras into small ones. For example mangalam Bhagwan Vishnu. This stotra is bit long. Can you please check in Yajurveda and try to find the complete chapter of this stotra

Comment: This is probably not from proper Yajurveda. Probably the supplementary texts like Aranyaka/Brahmana have it. I only have Sukla and Krishna Yajurveda but I don't have the Aranyakas/Brahmans part.

Comment: @Rickross what are Aranyaka/Brahmana texts? Are they part of Vedas?

Comment: With each Veda there is Aranyaka and Brahmana texts associated with it. They are like commentaries on Vedas to elucidate the terse contents of Vedas properly. You can get more info from Wiki.